# apex:outputlink is not working in Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning

```
<apex:column headerValue="Name">
    <apex:outputLink value="/{!result.id}" target="_self">
        <!--<apex:outputLink value="/apex/forceDetails?id={!result.id}">-->
        {!result['Name']}
    </apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
```

This outputlink is not working in Lightning !

Comment: You can try to using anchor tag <a href= "/{!result.id}" target="_self">{!result['Name']}</a>

Comment: It is always redirected to Classic Detail page,it should not be,if i click link in lightning,then it has to redirect to lightning detail view

Comment: In lightning we have different methods for redirect to detail page. You need to use that.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to redirect to another Salesforce record, you should consider using navigateToSObject redirect.

More details here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToSObject.htm

Outputlink is more appropriate for linking to external websites. If you use it here to link to other Salesforce records, it will either reload Salesforce, or open in classic.

The other issue with Outputlink is that it will end up opening the URL is mobile browser when a user taps on it from Salesforce1.